# Are Bitcoin's blocks signed by the miner?

Tags: mining-theory, signature

To my understanding, at no point in the Bitcoin Whitepaper does it say that blocks are signed by the miner. However, one could see the advantage of having blocks signed.

Thus I wonder if in the implementation of Bitcoin, blocks are signed by miners? Or maybe I missed it in the Whitepaper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A sort of. Not a cryptographic signature, but each miner is incentivized to use one of its own BTC addresses as recipient of coinbase (reward) transaction. This links the block to the miner, with the same strength each UTXO is linked to its owner (I want to stress that there isn't native identity concept in bitcoin's blockchain, so we can say that the attribution allowed by core methods is already implemented)

Can you elaborate on signature (maybe stronger one) advantages, from your POV? Thanks

Comment: Having the blocks signed would give more information about the miner than just the reward recipient (since the miner could choose to reward somebody else).
So say somebody wants to track the most active miners, looking at the signatures would be more revealing than looking at the reward recipient.

Even though miners could create new key pairs on the spot for each block mined, we would know for sure that the miner possesses the private key corresponding to THAT public key. Whereas with just the reward recipients, we cannot know for sure.

Comment: anonymity is usually considered a needed here (or at least a good property to have), it is not clear to me what greater benefits would be made by losing anonymity to the miners, more info is not always better

Comment: I don't think most of the mining pools believe in this anonymity mentioned above looking at the coinbase of blocks mined in last 24h. Example: `Y/
ViaBTC
/Mined by sadegh1515/,mm 6e[h׾iTv,?˟5nf]` in block [678169](https://btc.bitaps.com/678169) and other mining pools based on blocks in last 24h: F2Pool, EMCD, BTC, Binance, Antpool, Foundry, Poolin, Huobi, Okex, Slush, etc.

Comment: Regarding anonymity, not much will change with respect to the original concept, and I agree that more info is not always better. I just wanted to be sure that blocks were not signed, because one could make a case of why they should be (or should have been) signed.